# c segmentation fault, reading large file

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, malloc, large-files

I'm trying to read a file and store what it contains, but I'm getting segmentation fault, here is part of my code:

```
int nnodes;
    int main(){
    FILE * file = fopen("pub08.in", "r");
        int nkeys;
        fscanf(file, "%d %d", &nnodes, &nkeys);
        long int graphsize = nnodes * nnodes;
        long int * graph = malloc(graphsize * sizeof (long int));
        for (int i = 0; i < graphsize; i++) {
            graph[i] = IN;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < nnodes; i++) {
            long int a, b, prize;
            fscanf(file, "%ld %ld %ld", &a, &b, &prize);
            graph[a * nnodes + b] = prize;
            graph[b * nnodes + a] = prize;
        }
    }
```

the file pub08.in looks like this:

```
100000 10000
61268 56095 10
40567 20917 17
97937 47973 13
74088 21826 13
62183 30464 11
97793 80708 12
35121 90180 10
77067 97297 17
4657 33995 16
88147 42709 18
95937 25936 19
79853 24452 11
9677 36288 11
91869 48767 15
34585 46478 17
41874 40622 15
13700 19942 18
15660 79277 14
    ...
```

[Full file is here](https://mega.nz/#!pqQnkCzQ!6zetk2vxmKV4wuk-BRZKmzMyWC2RzQkCxfKTrlfXRPM)

The segmentation fault happens, I think, on line:

```
graph[a * nnodes + b] = prize;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are requesting around 4 or 8 GBs of memory (depending on your `sizeof(long int)`). Are you sure you have that much?

Comment: Oh right yeah, that's right. I don't actually. I only have one GB

Answer (score 1):

Here is a list of things you are doing wrong:

1. Check the return values from `fscanf`.
2. Validate `a` and `b` to ensure that they are in range.
3. Check the return value from `malloc`
4. As per comment - check the return value from `fopen`

Comment: Also, check the return of `fopen`.

Comment: Okay I noticed one problem, the long int graphsize isn't 10 000 000 000(how it should be), but 1 410 065 408 instead.  But why?:p

Comment: What is the return value from `fscanf`?

Comment: the first fscanf is 2, the second is 3 and then one line right below it the program fails

Comment: Please add the declarations for all the variables

Comment: the value of nnodes is 100 000, but nnodes*nnodes stores in graphsize as 1410065408, and it doesn't matter whether graphsize is long int or just int

Comment: What are the datatypes - you are missing that in the posted code

Comment: i.e. for `a`, `b` etc.,,